# What is μm? It shows up when I add some modifiers

Tags: units

I set the default unit of measurement to mm. The only way I've ever learned to use mu is as a symbol for averages. It seems out of place here to me. What does it mean? I expected it to be the default unit of measurement instead.

[image]

Comment: Mu is also the prefix for micro, in this case *micro*meters.

Comment: A micrometer is 1/1000 of a meter and is the same as millimeter mm

Comment: µ the _micro_ prefix signifies 1 millionth.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system#Prefixes_for_multiples_and_submultiples  FWIW in 2.8 with scene units, metric system, mm as length unit this displays as 0.01mm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your **unit setting** about **length** display method.

[image]

If you are using **adaptive**, the unit will change to better fit in relative concise number. In your case, `micrometer`.

[image]

You can also select `None` for unit system to avoid any unit displays in Blender

Comment: That was my first thought too, I tried it and it was 10um as in his picture, I think it was user error that he misclicked the unit and got confused

Answer (score -1):

µm is a unit of measure just like meter, millimeter and kilometer.

It's not out of place as it's a measurement

You've set the default measurement to mm, so you would expect mm. It's quite possible you selected the wrong measurement by accident.

you showed an image of the solidify modifier showing um, so now I've tried to recreate what you showed, and get the correct measurements in mm, then I selected the um and got the measurements in um.

So the error you are having is quite possible that you have selected micrometers instead of millimeters